# Angular2 Rollupjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rollupjs

I am trying to bundle my Angular2 app using RollupJS but I have been running into a few issues:

1. The css file referenced by my AppComponent couldn't be found and throws an error.

> Error transforming /demo-app.ts with 'angular' plugin: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, open /demo-app.css

To fix this I wrote a gulp task to compile my scss files to css. But I was under the impression that Rollup was able to do this.

2. An rxjs module is causing me errors.

> Module /node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.js does not export of (imported by /@angular/router/src/apply_redirects.js)

I have tried to use rollup-plugin-alias and writing a specific resolveRxJS function to fix this but no luck.

```
const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');
const eslint = require('rollup-plugin-eslint');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
const typescript = require('rollup-plugin-typescript');
const angular = require('rollup-plugin-angular');
const alias = require('rollup-plugin-alias');
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const progress = require('rollup-plugin-progress');
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');

export default {
    entry: 'src/demo-app/main.ts',
    dest: 'dist/demo-app/bundle.min.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourceMap: 'inline',
    plugins: [
        {
            resolveRxJS: id => {
                if (id.startsWith('rxjs/') || id.startsWith('rxjs\\')) {
                    let result = `${__dirname}/node_modules/rxjs-es/${id.replace('rxjs/', '')}.js`;
                    return result.replace(/\//g, "\\");
                }
            }
        },
        angular(),
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript'),
            tsconfig: tsOptions
        }),
        //alias({
        //    rxjs: __dirname + '/node_modules/rxjs'
        //}),
        babel({
            exclude: '/node_modules/**',
            include: '/node_modules/tslint-no-unused-var/**',
            // include: '/node_modules/rxjs/**'
        }),
        resolve({
            module: true,
            jsnext: true
        }),
    ]
}
```

The commented out code is other things I have tried. note: I have also tried using preprocessors in the rollup-plugin-angular function which also didn't compile my css.

So to recap 1) do I always have to compile my scss files with gulp before running the rollup code? 2) How do I fix the rxjs module issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check my working  repo , aot build with rollup enabled, https://github.com/beginor/angular-seed

Comment: I actually get a similar error with your code:  Unexpected token node_modules/rxjs/util/isArrayLike.js (2:78) this happens during the rollup code –

Comment: I am sure my sample works, it maybe caused by some libraries. Does it works for you now?

Comment: @BradBeighton It is caused by `rxjs:~5.2.0` , please use `rxjs:~5.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by adding the rollup-plugin-commonjs module and including the rxjs node_module library.

```
commonjs({
    include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**',
),
```